# What is it saying?

Tags: pronunciation

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUhRiycleuqZOHp2kxiY4AU22fZKS_t1/view?usp=sharing

After "bunch of people", what does it sound like?

What's the way for me to fully understand what it's said? I can never listen to what it suppose to be sound.

---

How did you guys listened "4:00 a.m."? No matter how I listen to, all I can hear was "I guess you emailed a bunch of people For ended up something?". I know the sentence doesn't make sense... Would you guys recommend me how I can improve my listening? English is my second language by the way.

Comment: I think the problem is the poor quality of the recording so this isn't really an English language question.

Comment: Note that "What is he saying?" is [off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/exactly-why-is-this-question-off-topic-or-not/5369#5369). The part "how do I understand this?" is more on-topic, but is likely to be *better* placed on [languagelearning.se] as a general question. Do check their Help files (from the question mark in the top bar on that site).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a transcription service.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scene from the 2015 film *The Intern*. The entire line is

> "And your 11:00 is in the big conference room. So is your 11:10. Finance needs you, and I guess you emailed a bunch of people at 4:00 a.m. about something?

I found the film by Googling the phrase "emailed a bunch of people at 4 AM" and translating the one link that popped up from Korean. From there, I searched for subtitles for the film.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like she is talking about some meeting or proposed meeting. She describes how they did or could feed a bunch of people and you *could call people at 4:00 AM on Sunday* apparently to tell them what a great meeting it is. Her tone suggests that she is not serious about doing that but just throwing it out as a wild idea.